# Issue in forming desired output with Day, Hour & Minute in Kotlin - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, datetime, calculation

I have below function which takes **totalMinutes** as an argument.

```
 fun minutesToDaysHoursMinutes(totalMinutes: Double): String? {
    var returnString = ""
    try {
        var minutes =0.0
        if (totalMinutes > 6000) {
            val days = totalMinutes / 1440
            val remainingMins = totalMinutes - (1440 * days) // 310
            var hours = remainingMins / 60
            minutes = remainingMins - (hours * 60)
            if (minutes >= 30) {
                hours += 1
            }
            returnString = String.format("%01dd %01dh", days.toInt(), (hours + 1).toInt())
        } else if (totalMinutes > 60) {
            returnString =
                String.format("%01dh %01dm", (totalMinutes / 60).toInt(), minutes.toInt())
        } else {
            returnString = String.format("%01dm", minutes.toInt())
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(">> e1", ">>> e5")
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return returnString
}
```

Calling function for 6050 minutes as :

`tvTimeToCharge.text = minutesToDaysHoursMinutes(6050.0)`

I am getting this output : **4d 0h**

But The output should be as **4d 5h**

Where I doing wrong?
The output requirement is as below :

> 6050 minutes is displayed as: 4d 5h (it is 4 days 4 hours and 50
> minutes, 50 minutes we round to 1 hour)
>
> 6090 minutes is displayed as: 4d 6h (it is 4 days 5 hours and 30
> minutes, 30 minutes we round to 1 hour)
>
> 6089 minutes is displayed as 4d 5h (it is 4 days 5 hours and 29
> minutes, 29 minutes we round to 0 hours)

Let me know if any. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
val days = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 1440)
var hours = Math.round((totalMinutes % 1440) / 60)
```

6050.0 / 1440 is 4.2days, Math.floor(4.2) is 4 days.
6050.0 % 1440 is 290 minutes, 290 / 60 is 4.8 hours, Math.round(4.8) is 5 hours.

Comment: And as @Praveen said, there are many useful time APIs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours() also works well. This is just a way to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing the whole logic yourself, more cleaner approach would be to use `Duration` class provided in `java 8` `time` API.

For using `java 8` `time` API in `android`, you have to enable `coreLibraryDesugaring` in your module.

In your app module's `build.gradle`, add `coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true`

```
compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Now, you can use the `Duration` class to calculate `day` and `hour` duration like this

```
val days = Duration.ofMinutes(totalMinutes.toLong()).toDays()
val hours = Duration.ofMinutes(totalMinutes.toLong()).toHoursPart() + 
            (Duration.ofMinutes(totalMinutes.toLong()).toMinutesPart() / 60.0).roundToInt()
```